# mobile data is turned off for _my app_

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework

I installed my ionic app on an iPhone and when I launch it I get this popup message:

```
Mobile data is turned off for _my app_
You can turn on mobile data for this app in Settings.
```

But I want to avoid this annoying message to all the users.

Can you help me figure this out, is there something to setup in ionic?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings -> Mobile Data -> Scroll down -> Use Mobile Data For -> Switch on for your app.

As far as I know, all apps start with this setting "on", so you must have set it "off" yourself?

Comment: Or Settings -> Scroll down to your own app -> Cellular Data